# What's wrong if not including GetRNGstate()?

Tags: r, rcpp

`GetRNGstate()` and `PutRNGstate()` are mysteries to me. I have read section 6.3 of **Writing R Extensions** but it only says "*the user must call*" them and "*These essentially read in (or create) .Random.seed and write it out after use*".

I initially thought that if I failed to include them then the `set.seed()` function in R will not be able to work on my Rcpp function. So I did some experiments but it turns out that nothing seems wrong without `GetRNGstate()` and `PutRNGstate()`. I feel that I must be missing something, so why and when should I include these two functions?

Below is my own experiment:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector myrv4(int n) {
  NumericVector x = rnorm(n, 0.0, 1.0);
  return x;
}
```

And my test results:

```
> n <- 2
> set.seed(1234)
> myrv4(n)
[1] -1.2070657  0.2774292
> set.seed(1234)
> myrv4(n)
[1] -1.2070657  0.2774292
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You missed the fact that using Rcpp Attributes includes it for you anyway, as it should.  Try building with `, verbose=TRUE` to see

```
 Rcpp::RNGScope __rngScope
```

inserted auto-*magic*-ally for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That perfectly answers my question!

Comment: Nice to hear -- feel free to "accept" (click on tickmark) and/or "upvote" (click on up-triangle) as is common here on StackOverflow.